# mocha-phantomjs test case for callback function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, callback, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

I have a module in which I have this function

```
flickrPhotoSearch: function (searchByName, flickrUserKey, numberOfImages, callbackData) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: commonConstants.BASE_URL + "flickr.photos.search&api_key=" + flickrUserKey + "&tags=" + searchByName + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function (jsonData) {
            if (jsonData.stat === commonConstants.JSON_SUCCESS) {
                if (jsonData.photos['photo'].length < commonConstants.DATA_LENGTH) {
                    callbackData(jsonData);
                } else {
                    var flickrImage = flickrApplication.jsonToImage(jsonData, numberOfImages);
                    callbackData(flickrImage);
                }
            } else {
                callbackData(jsonData);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I want to test this function and I choose `mocha-phantomjs` for it. And this is my test case

```
describe("flickrphotoSearch", function () {
    it("should fail with wrong key", function () {
        flickrApplication.flickrPhotoSearch(testConstant.CORRECT_NAME, testConstant.WRONG_KEY, testConstant.CONSTANT_ONE, handleData);
        function handleData (photoUrl) {
            assert.equals(photourl.stat, "pass", photoUrl.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Now this test should fail by giving error `"Invalid API Key"`. But It got passed. I think this is because I used assertion inside callback function i.e. `handleData()`.

I am using `mocha-phantomjs` setup and `chai` assertion library.

I searched for tutorials and demos but coudn't find any. Also I tried `mocha-phantomjs` examples but with no help I am posting here.

Please tell me how to test callback function in `mocha-phantomjs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is the typical symptom for a test that is *asynchronous* but is being tested *synchronously*. The solution is to use the `done` callback in your test:

```
it("should fail with wrong key", function (done) {
    flickrApplication.flickrPhotoSearch(testConstant.CORRECT_NAME, testConstant.WRONG_KEY, testConstant.CONSTANT_ONE, handleData);
    function handleData (photoUrl) {
        assert.equals(photourl.stat, "pass", photoUrl.message);
        done();
    }
});
```

When you add the `done` argument to the callback you give to `it`, you tell Mocha that the test is asynchronous and then you must call it in your asynchronous callback (`handleData` here) to tell Mocha that the test is over.

Otherwise, Mocha will run the callback given to `it` and won't wait for `handleData` to execute. The test will end right away, without errors, so Mocha will say it has passed.

Comment: Thanks It works. Also I made some changes that works for me. 
`function handleData (photoUrl, done) {
    assert.equal(photoUrl.stat, "pass", photoUrl.message);
    this.timeout(2000);
    setTimeout(done, 1500);
};`