# How to test Front-end of the node application using mocha and phantom.js

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, phantomjs, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

I made a single page application using `backbone(client-side), node(back-end)`. All the templating part was happening at client-side. I am using `node` for fetching,updating and setting data into database.

Until now, I used to test application manually, so I decided to test application with `mocha,chai,phantom and mocha-phantomjs`. Why I choose these libraries, because I can run test cases in terminal so later I can implement `Continuous Integration`.

So I installed all the libraries using `npm`.I started my node server,I can access my application through browser using`localhost:3004`(node server redirecting to my index.html file,which is places under public folder. Inside this file I didn't mention any mocha corresponding files.).Now I want to test my application,without open my application I can't able to test so I am planning to open through browser.I written the following code and saved as `InitialPageLoad.js`.

```
var mocha=require('mocha'),
chai=require('chai'),
mochaPhantomJS=require('mochaPhantomJS');
mocha.ui('bdd'); 
mochaPhantomJS.run();
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('localhost:3004', function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("login-name"));
});
```

My index.html looks like the following way.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Tests </title>
</head>
<body>
   //written my application corresponding templates and loading corresponding developer fiels
</body>
</html>
```

I switch to my project folder and then invoke the following code.

```
mocha-phantomjs public/testCases/InitialPageLoad.js
```

It's returning the following error

```
Failed to start mocha: Init timeout
```

First What I am doing, is it right or not.

Comment: It looks like it works: [mocha-phantomjs test case for callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22837124/1816580). If this helped, maybe you can write up a proper answer with everything that is necessary to do.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I updated my question, can you check it once.